# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, console.log

Im working on learning JavaScript at the moment and don't fully understand the error in my console. I'm not working on anything too complicated and when following tutorials, I never have issues. It's always when I try to practice a project on my own. My file structure follows as:

```
Task List
 -index.html
 -styles.css
 -app.js
```

I've seen on similar questions that it's an issue when it comes to linking other folders but my css and js are both being added correctly.

[Console.log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daTkj.png)

Comment: Please try to post errors as text in the question instead of linking to an external image where possible.

Comment: You can attempt to comprehend the errors as follows: 404 Not Found means that the requested path cannot be found on the server. The grey text to the right of the errors is the file name of the files that cannot be loaded. From the file names, I believe that you are trying to load in FontAwesome webfonts. Have you put the font files in the right places?

Answer (score 0):

It's not **founding the fonts** ([error 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)), try to **add them** or **delete the fonts** import.

So you copy pasted your html from a place that were using fonts, or you are not providing us a full project file structure.

If you would like to use an **icon library**, you should **import it**, ***using a CDN or downloading them***, those are fonts files. Follow the instructions in the project website, like [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

So:

1. You are trying to **directly use the font in the styles**, or...
2. You are **using an icon library class that implicitly relies on any of those fonts**.

Comment: I've been using the free Kit from Font Awesome. Besides that, I'm not importing any other libraries to my project. It just seems weird that the same Kit Link I used during my following of a tutorial is giving me this console error now. I just did the tutorial about 2 hours ago.

Comment: Are you importing it correctly? Order matters.

Comment: I've also tried removing the Font Awesome link but the error still appears. I'm not sure what font its trying to load but can't find.

Comment: Yeah I had the Font Awesome Kit link first followed by my styles sheet.

Comment: If you remove the link the error will persist, in order to remove the error you should delete every `<i>` tag that relies on a fontawesome class, like fa-SOMETHING, but that won't solve the problem, are you importing the font inside the `<head>` tag?

Please go to the FontAwesome page and check that the generated link is correct, and please, copy and paste the network tab information (F12 if you are using Chrome, CTRL+SHIFT+E if you are using Firefox).

Comment: Ok so when I delete all my icons, the error goes away even if I leave the Font Awesome Kit link in my head. I'm copying the link directly from Font Awesome so im assuming this probably has to do with the Kit link itself..? I can move forward with the app without this icon now that I know what was generating it. I think I'll just have to look at my account with Font Awesome.